# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ix(a-b)} d x $

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I would like to solve the following integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-ix(a-b)} d x
$$
a and b are real numbers.

Edit: the result should be $$\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}$$
I just found it on internet, but I still don't know how to demostrate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know about integration by parts?

Comment: I've tried integration by parts, but when I take the limit to infinity I am not sure about the bahavior of the complex exponential.

Comment: So I was trying to find another way, maybe with complex analysis, contour integration or something like that...

Comment: Your integral doesn't converge in the $\lim_{T\to \infty} \int_0^\infty$ sense.

Comment: Expression is not absolute integrable.  Integrand does not go to 0 for large x.  Integral exists?

Comment: It should result 1/(a-b)^2 but I don't know how to obtain that.

Comment: Do you know $\int_0^\infty xe^{-zx}dx=z^{-2}$ for $z>0$? If we define the integral for $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$ as $z^{-2}$ by analytic continuation, the integral you asked about should be $[i(a-b)]^{-2}=-(a-b)^{-2}$ (provided $a\ne b$), which differs from your intended result only in a sign.

Comment: The integral is not convergent and so has to be interpreted in another sense.

Answer (score 2):

The integral isn't convergent but can be reinterpreted as a Fourier transform of a distribution.

Using the "[non-unitary, angular frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions)" variant of the Fourier transform,
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ f(x) \} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, e^{-i\nu x} \, dx,
$$
we can interpret the given integral as $\mathcal{F}\{ x\, u(x) \},$ where $u(x)$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), then evaluated for $\nu=a-b.$

Using properties [107](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional) and [313](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions,_one-dimensional) we get
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ x \, u(x) \}
= i\frac{d}{d\nu} \mathcal{F}\{ u(x) \}
= i\pi \frac{d}{d\nu} \left( \frac{1}{i\pi\nu} + \delta(\nu) \right)
= i\pi \left( -\frac{1}{i\pi\nu^2} + \delta'(\nu) \right)
= -\frac{1}{\nu^2} + i\pi\delta'(\nu).
$$
Thus,
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-i(a-b)x} \, dx
= -\frac{1}{(a-b)^2} + i\pi\delta'(a-b).
$$
With the distributional meaning of these terms it's not necessary to put a condition $a\neq b,$ but for a classical meaning we require $a\neq b$ and then the second term vanishes and we are left with
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{-i(a-b)x} \, dx
= -\frac{1}{(a-b)^2}.
$$

Comment: You forgot an $x$ in the integral at the end. But except that, it is how I would do it +1

Comment: @LL3.14. The missing $x$ has been inserted.

Comment: Of course, the $1/(a-b)^2$ still needs to be interpreted as the analytic continuation of integration-against that not-locally $L^1$ function... but, indeed, "away from $a-b=0$, that can be ignored.

Comment: @paulgarrett. As a distribution, $\frac{1}{\nu^2}$ is a finite part distribution.

Comment: Yes, and/but a person in the situation of the questioner may not know about Hadamard's "finite-part" idea, nor how to justify it. Maybe even more direct to say it's the distribution derivative of the PV integral of $1/x$ (the latter being better known, I think).

Comment: @paulgarrett. I thought about mentioning "finite part" in the answer and provide a link to an explanation, but decided not to. I didn't like the description on the Wikipedia page and didn't care to look for a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Start by writing the integral in the following way:
\begin{eqnarray}
I(k)=\int_{0}^{\infty}dx xe^{-ikx}, \hspace{10pt}k=a-b.
\end{eqnarray}
The integrand can be rewritten as:
\begin{eqnarray}
I(k)=i\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{d}{dk}\left(e^{-ikx}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now consider performing the indefinite integral in $k$ and switch the order of integration on the RHS. This gives:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int I(k)dk = i\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\int dk\frac{d(e^{-ikx})}{dk}=i\int_{0}^{\infty}dxe^{-ikx} +C
\end{eqnarray}
where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Now, the above integral is not convergent; you might use a convergence parameter $\epsilon>0$ to write:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}dx e^{-ikx-\epsilon x}=\frac{e^{-ikx-\epsilon x}}{-ik-\epsilon}\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}=+\frac{1}{ik+\epsilon}
\end{eqnarray}
Multiplying by the prefactor $i$ we get:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\frac{i}{ik+\epsilon}=\frac{1}{k}
\end{eqnarray}
So in total we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int dk I(k)=C+\frac{1}{k}
\end{eqnarray}
The function $I(k)$ that provides this indefinite integral is:
\begin{eqnarray}
I(k)=\frac{(-1)}{k^{2}}=\frac{(-1)}{(a-b)^{2}}
\end{eqnarray}
so the integral is evaluated.